# Building a Mezzanine Office 2x10s or 2x122

Tags: deck

Working on building a mezzanine in my shop for a small office. I am currently trying to figure out the best way to build it. I am thinking 2x6 walls 24OC and 2x10s 12OC. 16 FT Span. Should I upgrade to 2x12s 16OC or will the 2x10s work?
[image]

Comment: No bracing shown in the drawing, don't forget about that!

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. This is probably too opinion-based a question for this site's format. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: @DanielGriscom What is “opinion based” about a structural design issue?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming ordinary loads on the floor and etc. you can look this up on a span table, such as [this one](https://www.mycarpentry.com/joist-span-table.html).

[image: Joist Span Tables]

This shows that for a 16' span, 2x10's spaced 12" on center are adequate even with the Eastern spruce number for a 40#/ft-ft live load.

You could get by with 2x8's if you use #1 grade yellow pine and only need to support a 30#/ft-ft live load, but I'd much rather leave some room for error than try to squeak by.

With 2x12's, you can actually get by with 24" spacing, although that's going to be a springy floor, it's probably a significant savings.  Spruce will make it, but you could probably upgrade from spruce to #1 or #2 yellow pine for some room for error and still come out ahead.